# Argo request limit not reflecting on argo UI

Tags: kubernetes, request, argo-workflows, argo

I am trying to reduce the cpu that my pod runs on by half but it does not reflect on the UI. The default is 1 cpu but I want to reduce it to 0.5 but it shows 1.

```
apiVersion: argoproj.io/v1alpha1
kind: Workflow
metadata:
  generateName: pod-spec-patch-
spec:
  entrypoint: whalesay
  arguments:
    parameters:
      - name: cpu-limit
        value: 50m
      - name: mem-limit
        value: 100Mi
  podSpecPatch: |
    containers:
      - name: main
        resources:
          limits:
            memory: "{{workflow.parameters.mem-limit}}"
  templates:
  - name: whalesay
    podSpecPatch: '{"containers":[{"name":"main", "resources":{"limits":{"cpu": "{{workflow.parameters.cpu-limit}}" }}}]}'
    container:
      image: docker/whalesay:latest
      command: [cowsay]
      args: ["hello world"]
```

[image]

How do I check the amount of cpu used.